# openCV not working with python3

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I am getting this error while running a simple Python3 with opencv program on ubuntu 16.10.

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented.
Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you
are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then
re-run cmake or configure script) in cvShowImage, file
/io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 583 Traceback (most
recent call last):   File "samplecv.py", line 3, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('image',img) cv2.error: /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:583: error: (-2) The
function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+
2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in
function cvShowImage
```

The program I ran is:

```
  import cv2
    img = cv2.imread('my.jpg',0)
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
```

I have already checked similar questions [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655969/opencv-error-the-function-is-not-implemented) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40207011/opencv-not-working-properly-with-python-on-linux-with-anaconda-getting-error-th). And have re-installed opencv but it didnt help.

Comment: If you installed OpenCV through Python PIP, [it's well known that the Python wrappers are not compiled with GTK support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43531919/3250829), so you are not able to show an image on the screen and hence those errors.  The only choice you have is to compile the source to generate the right Python packages so that you can show images.  These directions from PyImageSearch are quite good: http://pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/20/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-3-4-on-ubuntu/.  Be prepared to spend between 30 minutes to an hour depending on your system configuration and setup.

Comment: thanks its done now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took more than 2 hours but its done now!
*I went to [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html) documentation of opencv and followed the step to install opencv 3.3.0-dev.
After complete installation it was still not working so i uninstalled the opencv-python using*

```
sudo pip3 uninstall opencv-python
```

*now errors were not showing up but still the image was not displayed until i added*

```
cv2.waitKey()
```

at the end of the program.
Now its working fine!!!

Comment: Yes you must use `waitKey`. A lot of users forget to do this.

Answer (score 0):

What you had tried is more suitable for python2. You are using python3 (as I can see from your question). I guess you're installing cv module using pip3 install command. It works but provides the module with decreased functionality: as you see for one from highgui module 'The
function is not implemented.'

The solution: try the 1st answer [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37188623/ubuntu-how-to-install-opencv-for-python3) and install opencv module manually step-by-step as described.

Comment: the `cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON`  .. was giving error . Anyways i sorted it out thank you!