# OpenCV compile process fails

Tags: macos, opencv, ffmpeg

So I'm following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37190408/2750877) post on how to install openCV for Python 3. And I'm running into some issues at the compile process. Running the `make -j4` command goes fine up until it's 28% through when I get this error message: `error: use of undeclared identifier 'avcodec_free_frame'; did you mean 'avcodec_get_name'?`

I don't even know where to start to solve this issue. I've got `ffmpeg` installed through brew.

Complete list of commands:

```
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git
cd opencv
git checkout 3.0.0
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib.git
cd opencv_contrib
git checkout 3.0.0
cd ~/opencv
mkdir build
cd build
cmake CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
    -D PYTHON3_LIBRARY=/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m/libpython3.5.dylib \
    -D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m/ \
    -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/python \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON .. \
    -D FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.4/include/
    -D FFMPEG_LIB_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.4/lib/
    -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON
cmake
make -j4
```

I got the `FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIR`, `FFMPEG_LIB_DIR` and `WITH_FFMPEG` from this post: http://blog.jiashen.me/2014/12/23/build-opencv-3-on-mac-os-x-with-python-3-and-ffmpeg-support/

The full error log:

```
[ 28%] Building CXX object modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_qtkit.mm.o
In file included from /Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:
/Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:317:9: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'avcodec_free_frame'; did you mean 'avcodec_get_name'?
        avcodec_free_frame(&picture);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        avcodec_get_name
/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.4/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:6289:13: note: 'avcodec_get_name' declared here
const char *avcodec_get_name(enum AVCodecID id);
            ^
In file included from /Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:
/Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:317:28: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type
      'enum AVCodecID' with an rvalue of type 'AVFrame **'
        avcodec_free_frame(&picture);
                           ^~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.4/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:6289:45: note: passing argument to parameter 'id' here
const char *avcodec_get_name(enum AVCodecID id);
                                            ^
In file included from /Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:
/Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:632:23: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'avcodec_alloc_frame'
            picture = avcodec_alloc_frame();
                      ^
/Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:635:41: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'PIX_FMT_BGR24'; did you mean 'AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24'?
                    avpicture_get_size( PIX_FMT_BGR24,
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                        AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24
/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.4/include/libavutil/pixfmt.h:65:5: note: 'AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24' declared here
    AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24,     ///< packed RGB 8:8:8, 24bpp, BGRBGR...
    ^
In file included from /Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:
/Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:638:29: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'PIX_FMT_BGR24'; did you mean 'AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24'?
                            PIX_FMT_BGR24, enc->width, enc->height );
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                            AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24
/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.4/include/libavutil/pixfmt.h:65:5: note: 'AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24' declared here
    AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24,     ///< packed RGB 8:8:8, 24bpp, BGRBGR...
    ^
In file included from /Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:
/Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:738:67: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'PIX_FMT_RGB24'; did you mean 'AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24'?
    avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)&rgb_picture, rgb_picture.data[0], PIX_FMT_RGB24,
                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                  AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24
/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.4/include/libavutil/pixfmt.h:64:5: note: 'AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24' declared here
    AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24,     ///< packed RGB 8:8:8, 24bpp, RGBRGB...
    ^
In file included from /Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:
/Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:756:17: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'PIX_FMT_BGR24'; did you mean 'AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24'?
                PIX_FMT_BGR24,
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24
/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.4/include/libavutil/pixfmt.h:65:5: note: 'AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24' declared here
    AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24,     ///< packed RGB 8:8:8, 24bpp, BGRBGR...
    ^
In file included from /Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:
/Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1110:15: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'avcodec_alloc_frame'
    picture = avcodec_alloc_frame();
              ^
/Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1113:33: error: unknown type name 'PixelFormat'; did you
      mean 'AVPixelFormat'?
    size = avpicture_get_size( (PixelFormat) pix_fmt, width, height);
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~
                                AVPixelFormat
/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.4/include/libavutil/pixfmt.h:60:6: note: 'AVPixelFormat' declared here
enum AVPixelFormat {
     ^
In file included from /Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:
/Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1122:25: error: unknown type name 'PixelFormat'; did you
      mean 'AVPixelFormat'?
                       (PixelFormat) pix_fmt, width, height);
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~
                        AVPixelFormat
/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.4/include/libavutil/pixfmt.h:60:6: note: 'AVPixelFormat' declared here
enum AVPixelFormat {
     ^
In file included from /Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:
/Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1230:19: error: unknown type name 'PixelFormat'; did you
      mean 'AVPixelFormat'?
    c->pix_fmt = (PixelFormat) pixel_format;
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~
                  AVPixelFormat
/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.4/include/libavutil/pixfmt.h:60:6: note: 'AVPixelFormat' declared here
enum AVPixelFormat {
     ^
In file included from /Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:
/Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1405:26: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'PIX_FMT_BGR24'; did you mean 'AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24'?
    if (input_pix_fmt == PIX_FMT_BGR24) {
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                         AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24
/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.4/include/libavutil/pixfmt.h:65:5: note: 'AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24' declared here
    AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24,     ///< packed RGB 8:8:8, 24bpp, BGRBGR...
    ^
In file included from /Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:
/Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1410:31: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'PIX_FMT_GRAY8'; did you mean 'AV_PIX_FMT_GRAY8'?
    else if (input_pix_fmt == PIX_FMT_GRAY8) {
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                              AV_PIX_FMT_GRAY8
/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.4/include/libavutil/pixfmt.h:70:5: note: 'AV_PIX_FMT_GRAY8' declared here
    AV_PIX_FMT_GRAY8,     ///<        Y        ,  8bpp
    ^
In file included from /Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:
/Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1423:25: error: unknown type name 'PixelFormat'; did you
      mean 'AVPixelFormat'?
                       (PixelFormat)input_pix_fmt, width, height);
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~
                        AVPixelFormat
/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.4/include/libavutil/pixfmt.h:60:6: note: 'AVPixelFormat' declared here
enum AVPixelFormat {
     ^
In file included from /Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:
/Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1429:47: error: unknown type name 'PixelFormat'; did you
      mean 'AVPixelFormat'?
                                             (PixelFormat)input_pix_fmt,
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~
                                              AVPixelFormat
/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.4/include/libavutil/pixfmt.h:60:6: note: 'AVPixelFormat' declared here
enum AVPixelFormat {
     ^
In file included from /Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:
/Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1447:25: error: unknown type name 'PixelFormat'; did you
      mean 'AVPixelFormat'?
                       (PixelFormat)input_pix_fmt, width, height);
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~
                        AVPixelFormat
/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.4/include/libavutil/pixfmt.h:60:6: note: 'AVPixelFormat' declared here
enum AVPixelFormat {
     ^
In file included from /Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:
/Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1604:25: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'PIX_FMT_BGR24'; did you mean 'AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24'?
        input_pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_BGR24;
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                        AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24
/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.4/include/libavutil/pixfmt.h:65:5: note: 'AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24' declared here
    AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24,     ///< packed RGB 8:8:8, 24bpp, BGRBGR...
    ^
In file included from /Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:
/Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1607:25: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'PIX_FMT_GRAY8'; did you mean 'AV_PIX_FMT_GRAY8'?
        input_pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_GRAY8;
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                        AV_PIX_FMT_GRAY8
/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.4/include/libavutil/pixfmt.h:70:5: note: 'AV_PIX_FMT_GRAY8' declared here
    AV_PIX_FMT_GRAY8,     ///<        Y        ,  8bpp
    ^
In file included from /Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:
/Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1683:25: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'PIX_FMT_YUV422P'; did you mean 'AV_PIX_FMT_YUV422P'?
        codec_pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_YUV422P;
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                        AV_PIX_FMT_YUV422P
/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.4/include/libavutil/pixfmt.h:66:5: note: 'AV_PIX_FMT_YUV422P' declared here
    AV_PIX_FMT_YUV422P,   ///< planar YUV 4:2:2, 16bpp, (1 Cr & Cb sample per 2x1 Y samples)
    ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/Users/myuser/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_qtkit.mm:46:9: fatal error: 'QTKit/QTKit.h' file not found
#import <QTKit/QTKit.h>
        ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_qtkit.mm.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This question on openCV's website seems to adress the same issue but there is no solution posted: http://answers.opencv.org/question/90091/error-use-of-undeclared-identifier-avcodec_free_frame-did-you-mean-avcodec_get_name/

Comment: Can you add the terminal commands? especially the one that leads to that error!

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/05/macos-install-opencv-3-and-python-3-5/) out

Comment: Updated the post now @Ja_cpp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`avcodec_free_frame`, `PixelFormat` and `PIX_FMT_xxx` are deprecated in `ffmpeg` long ago. I'm pretty sure they don't even exist in 3.3.4 or current master branch.

So the opencv version you checked out must be too old to built with ffmpeg 3.3.4, and maybe only compatible with ffmpeg 2 series.

Opencv has updated ffmpeg compatibility in recent commits, like [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/d9e364f31f9e12a2cee9f8c2f17237b786cc1461/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp#L499). You can see the conditional macro to fit different ffmpeg API, the newer `av_frame_free` and older `avcodec_frame_free`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I checkout out the master branch in opencv and built it from there, worked better, I got passed the errors I had in my OP, but now I'm facing this error instead:
`/Users/myuser/opencv_contrib/modules/optflow/src/motempl.cpp:56:47: error: no member named 'video' in namespace
      'cv::ocl'
    ocl::Kernel k("updateMotionHistory", ocl::video::updatemotionhistory_oclsrc);
`

Comment: @bork have u updated the contrib repo?  There is no such line in master branch.

Comment: It was resolved when I cleared the Cmake cache. Going to mark this as the answer as it solved the specific issue I posted about!

Answer (score 1):

From the error log, it looks like you have ffmpeg version 3.3.3 while you forced cmake to look for version 3.3.4 headers and libraries. You should clear CMake cache and let it detect ffmpeg automatically. Or you can do `brew upgrade ffmpeg` to upgrade your ffmpeg to 3.3.4.

Also, I'd suggest using the lastest version of CMake GUI [here](https://cmake.org/download/).

Comment: I've upgraded ffmpeg to 3.3.4 and I still get the same errors.

Comment: Could you be more specific on **how** to clear Cmake cache please?

Comment: in your build folder: `rm -rf CMakeCache.txt CMakeFiles`