# How to use install modules on linux ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, python-3.4

I use OS LUbuntu

I installed Python3.4 using the Lubuntu software center;
[image]

Next thing I want to do is to install some modules.
Best way I can think of would be `pip install`. But I can't find it on the computer (I'm quite new to Linux).

Please help reaching the pip? or other way to install modules except pip?

I tried `sudo apt-get install ...` , but It installs it on `python2.7` instead of `python3.4` (I have 2 interpreters). Removing `python2.7` off the computer is not an option..

Comment: See [this](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/).

Comment: @Tomothy32 This is another option but I'd rather use the "sudo apt-get install..." option. But once I do it, it installs it on 2.7. I need it on 3.4

Comment: @Tomothy32 - The python3 libraries in ubuntu have a `python3` prefix, e.g.: `sudo apt-get install python3-pil`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu, how to install OpenCV for python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37188623/ubuntu-how-to-install-opencv-for-python3)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%5Bubuntu%5D+install+opencv

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sudo apt-get install pip3?

Ok, as someone has pointed out it is not actually pip3, it is a symlink. For a better answer we can look at the official python documentation.
https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html
and here we find:
python2   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 2
python2.7 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 2.7
python3   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 3
python3.4 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 3.4

So, if you want to install the Python 3 version of a package use

python3   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 3

Comment: I have yet to try, because I still try to use "sudo apt-get install <module>" rather than using pip3. Because I only need one module for temporary usage. Problem is, once I do this "sudo..." it installs it with 2.7. I need it to be installed with 3.7

Comment: @mikeg There is no `pip3` in Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, there is no actual pip3. It is just a symlink to pip. So, lets look at the documentation. https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html.  Here we see : py -2   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 2
py -2.7 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 2.7
py -3   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 3
py -3.4 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 3.4

Answer (score 0):

You have stated that you want to use `apt-get` instead of `pip`, so:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-<package_name>
```

The important part of this is the `3`. But honestly, `pip` is easier to use and more "meant" for Python, so I don't see a reason not to use it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it later. I rather use "apt-get" because this is temporary usage of python. I only need 1 module.

Comment: Update: Reading package lists... done ; building dependency tree ; reading state information... done; E: Unable to locate package python3-opencv

This is the error I got after trying this

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python3-opencv` and see what happens.

Comment: Honestly, sorry, but `pip` is the easiest way to solve your problems.

Comment: When I try sudo apt-get install pip3 I get `unable to locate package pip3`

Comment: Try `python3-pip`.