# No Module name 'dns' in Eclipse Pydev

Tags: python, mysql, dns, pip, pydev

I am using PyDev in Eclipse Mars to build my project. I used '''import mysql.connector''' but I get an exception through it:

```
 "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    import dns.resolver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dns'
```

There is **no option of using pip** in Preference>Pydev>Python Interpreters, so I tried adding dns & dnspython module library globally(which I was able to), yet I am getting the same exception.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you mind editing your question and providing some details about how you installed dnspython globally?

Comment: Also, this answer to a similar question might help you out - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6076903/9638991

Answer (score 0):

@Mayuresh Vadhyar there's actually a `Manage with pip` button in `Preferences > PyDev > Interpreters > Python Interpreter` that you could use to do `pip install <library>`.

Or you could also use `pip` from the command line (PyDev should pick it up automatically after you install it).

As for having the error, this means something didn't go well when you installed the module globally... can you give more details on which steps did you do when you did that? -- I'm not sure what `installing a module globally` means here...