# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SCons' when trying to build a project on Eclipse with scons

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.6, scons

I am trying to build a project with scons on Eclipse. When I do, the command line outputs the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<<<scons-location>>>/scons", line 5, in <module>
    from SCons.Script.Main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SCons'
```

I noticed that the SCons folder is installed somewhere else in the system, but I just don't know how to tell Eclipse where to find it. I tried putting its location onto the path.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding python modules to pydev in eclipse results in import error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070423/adding-python-modules-to-pydev-in-eclipse-results-in-import-error)

Comment: None of the suggestions in that post helped, unfortunately :(

Comment: How did you install SCons on your system? Which Python? Which version of SCons? What Distro/Release?  What command line is Eclipse trying to run to run SCons?

Comment: @bdbaddog , SCons was installed with Pip (Python3.6). The version of SCons is 4.3.0.

Comment: What's the command line eclipse is using to run scons?  Is eclipse pointing at the python you installed scons with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I found that worked with my specific case had to do with the PYTHONUSERBASE environment variable being modified at the wrong time, and in the wrong way. Fixing that also fixed the issue. Thanks to anyone who helped!